# Regex that matches 2 words not separated by a 3rd word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will match two words (in order) but cannot have another word/characters between them.

```
I need a match when "Spanish" & "Audio" are not separated by "<br />"
```

Test String:

```
Dolby Digital Audio 2.0 Language French<br /> Dolby Digital 5.1 
Audio Language Spanish<br /> Dolby Digital Audio Language 7.1 
English<br /> Subtitles Language Spanish <br />
```

False positive:

```
/Audio.*((?!\<br\ \>).).*Spanish/i
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use a DOM parser to extract text nodes one by one and then search each text node for what you need.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte While I'm usually first on board the "don't use regex to parse HTML", this seems like a pretty simple use-case that probably doesn't need a parser (assuming OP is doing something along the lines of grepping for information once, and not incorporating this into a larger, repeated, query).

Comment: Keep it simple - https://regex101.com/r/22ePpU/1

Comment: @0m3r Your link is not helpful because it fails to recognize that the test string does not represent all strings that could be encountered.  Please delete your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the tips mickmackusa.  I'm trying to check an xml feed field for a match.  If anywhere in the field,  the words "audio" and "spanish" are present and don't have a line break ("<br />" between them there should be a positive match.  

Regex is my only option.  Sorry if my question was not clear enough.  I actually put a lot of thought into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'd like to capture one or more words between "Audio" and "Spanish", unless those words contain `<br />`.

#### What's the problem?

The first `.*` matches `<br />`, and then the negative lookahead matches the space between `<br />` and `Spanish`.

#### What to do to solve it?

```
Audio\s*((?:(?!<br\ \/>).)*?)\s*Spanish
```

Broken down a bit:

```
Audio
\s*
(                    # the capture group
  (?:
    (?!<br\ \/>).    # any character such that it doesn't begin the string "<br />"
  )*?                # 0+ times; lazy
)
\s*
Spanish
```

You can [see it in action](https://regex101.com/r/NwTTqH/4).

---

The above is an edited post; previous iterations:

```
Audio\s*((?!\s*\<br\ \/>).*?)\s*Spanish
```

Thanks to Christian for pointing out that the above would match if `<br />` were preceded by non-space characters, e.g. `Audio foo <br /> Spanish`.

```
Audio\s*((?!.*\<br\ \/>).*?)\s*Spanish
```

This was still pretty flawed and failed if there was a trailing `<br />` after "Spanish".

Comment: How would you exclude a match for, say, `Audio foo <br /> bar Spanish`?

Comment: That works for the test string as shown in my question.  However, for some reason this isn't work if the entire test string is only one line:

> Dolby Digital Audio 2.0 Language French<br /> Dolby Digital 5.1 Audio Language Spanish<br /> Dolby Digital Audio Language 7.1 English<br /> Subtitles Language Spanish <br />

Comment: @dyna Yikes! I have no excuse for not checking that case, or for taking 3 tries to get it right; I guess I'm just having an off-day. I gave it a bit more thought and shifted quantifiers around to make the regex accurately reflect the problem.

Comment: @KernelPanic Thank you so much.  That does work perfectly.  I hope your dinner was a good one.

Comment: @KernelPanic: why did you insert the outer capture group? Wouldn't you get the same results without it?

Comment: @Christian it seemed like OP wanted to capture the whole "inner word", and otherwise the inner group would only capture the last character.